# How do I submit a multi step form to my database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a survey/questionnaire using the multistep form this link: (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) , but I can't seem to get it to submit the input to my database.

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=treasure", "root", "");
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
{
 sleep(5);
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO personal_information 
 (fname, lname, age, dob, gender, relationship) VALUES 
 (:fname, :lname, :age, :dob, :gender, :relationship)
 ";

 $user_data = array(
  ':fname'  => $_POST["fname"],
  ':lname'  => $_POST["lname"],
  ':age'   => $_POST["age"],
  ':dob'   => $_POST["dob"],
  ':gender'   => $_POST["gender"],
  ':relationship'   => $_POST["relationship"]

 );
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 if($statement->execute($user_data))
 {
  $message = '
  <div class="alert alert-success">
  Registration Completed Successfully
  </div>
  ';
  header("Location:survey_dashboard.php");
 }
 else
 {
  $message = '
  <div class="alert alert-success">
  There is an error in Registration
  </div>
  ';
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<form id="regForm" method="post">
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 ">Personal Information</h1>
    <p><center>(Please answer all questions as accuractely and honestly as possibly)</center></p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
  <label> What Is Your Name:</label>
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
  <label>What Is Your Age:</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" value="" min="1">
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
  <label>What Is Your Date Of Birth:</label>
  <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
  </div>

  <center><div class="tab">what is your gender:
    <div class="col-sm-2"><br>
    <select class="form-control inputstl" id="gender" name="gender">
        <option selected disabled> Select </option>
        <option> Male </option>
        <option> Female</option>
        <option> Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>  
  </div></center>
  <center><div class="tab">what is your relationship Status:
    <div class="col-sm-2"><br>
    <select class="form-control inputstl" id="relationship" name="relationship">
        <option selected disabled> Select </option>
        <option> Single Never Married </option>
        <option> Domestic Partnership</option>
        <option> Married</option>
        <option> Seperated</option>
        <option> Prefer Not to say</option>
        <option> None Of The Above</option>
    </select>
    </div>  
  </div></center>
  <center><div class="tab">
    <p>we care about the quality of our survey data and hope to receive the most
    accurate measures of your opinions, so it is important to us that you thoughtfully
    provide your best answer to each question in the survey, Do you commit to providing
    your thoughtful and honest answers to the questions in the survey?</p>  
  </div></center><br>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a multiple step form with navigation bar which works fine after a few battles... I tried implementing the same thing unto this but when I hit submit it just takes me back to question 1 without anything in the database... and my issue is not from the database. like i said i have applied similar principles already.....

Comment: Too much code. This is a great time for you to start learning how to debug. A Google search for something like "how to debug PHP" will get you started. If you're using an IDE it probably has helpful debugging tools. Even if you're not, you can still do some basic debugging by outputting key values throughout your code, running it, and observing that output. Use this process to narrow down the problem. If your code is doing something you don't expect, then somewhere in your code a specific operation is producing a result you didn't expect. Find that operation, determine the values at that time.

Comment: Isn't it that you check `if(isset($_POST["email"])) {...` but you don't even have an `email` field?

Comment: cyborg86pl even when i write it as ````if(isset($_post["regForm"])) {...```` it still does the exact same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST["fname"]))
```

it will work,
you have to know that the email is not posting ever and your chekng isset for email.